# Azure: Connect to key vault from cloud worker via certificate

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services, x509certificate2, azure-keyvault

I have a worker process running as a classic cloud service in Azure. This process needs to retrieve a value from an Azure key vault, and I need to keep the vault authentication secret outside my source tree.

Managed identities don't seem to be available for classic cloud workers, so I'm looking at certificates instead. I have gotten authentication by certificates to work locally, by creating a certificate and then uploading in Azure Active Directory for my app registration:

Certificate creation:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=MyFineCertificate" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature
```

Code that uses it to connect to a key vault (works locally):

```
private static KeyVaultClient GetClient()
{
    var certificate = GetCertificate();
    var assertion = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);
    var client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback((a, r, s) => GetAccessTokenUsingCert(a, r, s, assertion)));
    return client;
}

private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
{
    var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var results = certStore.Certificates.Find(/* criteria */);
    return results[0];
}

private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope, ClientAssertionCertificate cert)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, cert);
    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

So far so good. However, I want my Azure cloud worker to do this, so I need my certificate available there. My naive assumption was that I could, from the "Certificates" panel for my cloud worker in the portal, upload the certificate (pfx).

Unfortunately my cloud worker isn't able to find it. If I run this on Azure, after uploading my certificate, it doesn't show up:

```
foreach (StoreName name in Enum.GetValues(typeof(StoreName)))
{
    foreach (StoreLocation location in Enum.GetValues(typeof(StoreLocation)))
    {
        var certStore = new X509Store(name, location);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        foreach (var res in certStore.Certificates)
        {
            /* log certificate */
        }
    }
}
```

Why isn't it showing up? Am I even on the right track, or have I completely misunderstood how this works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two parts to your question here:

1. **Approach** - As Managed Service Identity is not available with Cloud Services, how to work/authenticate with Azure Key Vault?

   You are on the right track. I have described the approach for a similar problem to work with Key Vault in this SO Post - **[Securing sensitive information in Azure Cloud Service Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383440/securing-sensitive-information-in-azure-cloud-service-configuration/52386467#52386467)**
2. **Implementation** - specifically how to access the self-signed certificate from cloud service role instance.

   I think you might be missing to specify the certificate and it's location in the cloud service definition and configuration files. You should try adding something like this -

   CSCFG

   ```
    <Certificates>
        <Certificate name="MyFineCertificate" thumbprint="<my_thumbprint>" thumbprintAlgorithm="<my_thumbprint_algo e.g. sha1>" />
    </Certificates>
   ```

   CSDEF

   ```
    <Certificates>
         <Certificate name="MyFineCertificate" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
    </Certificates>
   ```

   Notice that I've mentioned store location as LocalMachine. Now, you should be able to access the certificate from your code by specifying the right location.

   ```
   var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
   ```

Comment: Rohit, your analysis was spot-on! Adding the certificate configuration element was indeed the missing piece. My cloud worker can now find the certificate under (my, local machine). Thank you!